# /bin/sh: 0: Can't open sh

Tags: shell, command-line, exec

I'm trying to run a simple C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern char** environ;

int main(){
//  execl("/bin/sh","sh","-c","/bin/ls -l",(char *) NULL);
    char* argv[] = {"/bin/sh","sh","-c","/bin/ls", (char*) NULL};
    execve(argv[0], argv, environ);
    return 0;
}
```

The commented out execl runs fine. But when I try to do the same with execve, then the compiler invokes the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open sh
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: As an aside, you're not initialising environ. If you want to pass your program's environmental strings to the child process, use execv() not execve()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
char* argv[] = {"/bin/sh","sh","-c","/bin/ls", (char*) NULL};
execve(argv[0], argv, environ);
```

Note that you're using `argv[0]` (`/bin/sh`) twice, once as the first argument to `execve()`, and another time as part of the array passed as the second argument to it. This is not what happens in your `execl()` invocation, 
there you only have `/bin/sh` as the first argument (the program file).

So, your `execve()` executes the file `/bin/sh`, giving it the program name (zeroth argument) of `/bin/sh`, and the regular arguments `sh`, `-c`, `/bin/ls`.
This is pretty much the same as calling `execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "/bin/ls", (char*) NULL)`.
Or in a shell command line:

```
$ /bin/sh sh -c /bin/ls
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open sh
```

That tells the shell to try and run a script called `sh` in the current directory, and the error message is what Dash gives for that if the script doesn't exist. The zero is probably the line number for a command line argument. (Bash gives a similar but different error message, and seems to look for the script from the `PATH` too. I'm not sure if the standard says anything about using `PATH` here.)

You could instead do

```
char *program = "/bin/sh";
char *argv[] = {"sh", "-c", "/bin/ls", NULL};
execve(program, argv, environ);
```

or maybe

```
char *argv[] = {"/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "/bin/ls", NULL};
execve(argv[0], argv + 1, environ);
```

Comment: Setting ``char* argv[] = {"/bin/sh","-c","/bin/ls -l", NULL};`` gives the intended output (same as ``execl``). Why is it so? Why do I need to pass ``sh`` to ``execl`` and not to ``execv``?

Comment: @Robur_131 It gives the same output, and in this case (in your comment), you call `/bin/sh` with `/bin/sh` instead of `sh` as the zeroth argument. See how you use `argv[0]` and `argv` in the call to `execve()`?

Comment: Yes, I noticed it. Thank you for your comment. @Kusalananda

Comment: puh, I think I came off a little too bluntly last night, so edited to tone down a bit. @Robur_131, I hope you got the problem fixed anyway. (And thanks to K for putting it simply.)

Comment: @Kusalananda, hmm yeah, not in the array initialization. But in the arguments to `execl()` it should be used, I think. (Not that I know of a machine where it would make a difference.)